# prove statement. cyclic sum complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, summation

If $(a+b)^3 = (b+c)^3 = (c+a)³\,\,\,\,a,b,c\,\,\in\mathbb{C},\,\,a\neq b\neq c$, show that $a^3 = b^3 = c^3$.

Some hints would be great.

Comment: Utilize a pair at a time form  linear relations of $a,b,c$

Comment: you mean I should make use of: (a+b)³ = (b+c)³, (b+c)³ = (a+c)³, (a+c)³ = (a+b)³.

Comment: please validate the existing ques

Comment: if we can prove: a + b + c = 0 then we're done.

Comment: @user1954946, won't the last exponent be $3??$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, I don't get your question.

Comment: @user1954946, will the last term be $(c+a)^3$ (cube not square)

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, yes the last term is (c+a)³

Answer (score 1):

As $\displaystyle a\ne c, a+b\ne b+c\implies \frac{a+c}{b+c}\ne1$

So, from $\displaystyle(a+b)^3 = (b+c)^3 = (c+a)^3\implies a+b=\omega(b+c)=\omega^2(c+a)$ where $\omega$ is one of the two complex [cube root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity#Examples) of unity

From   $\displaystyle a+b=\omega(b+c),a+b(1-\omega)-c \omega=0\ \ \ \ (1)$

From  $\displaystyle\omega(b+c)=\omega^2(c+a),-a\omega^2+b\omega+c(\omega-\omega^2)=0\ \ \ \ (2)$

Solve for $a,b$ in terms of $c,$ then take the  cubes